# How do I search for a vault item from inside a recipe?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

I have a vault item that looks like this:

```
{
  "id": "myvaultitem",
  "username": "myuser",
  "password": "mypass"
}
```

How can I grab a vault in a recipe that matches `username:myuser`? Could I do a wildcard search to load all vaults matching `id:my*`?

Of course I can search with knife, but I want to do this via a recipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access vault items via the `chef_vault_item()` API. You can't search values like that as they are encrypted server side.

Comment: duh I can't believe I didn't figure that out.  Can I search by vault item name? The name of a vault item isn't encrypted.

Comment: Yes but it wouldn't be super useful.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: Same as any other data bag with the `search` method.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you have multiple related values they probably belong in a single vault item.